# Tkinter Radiobutton Text

Tags: python, graphics, tkinter

I have the following code:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, master): # master is a Tk or Toplevel instance
        self.master, self.typeFrame = master, tk.Frame(master)
        self.typeVar = tk.StringVar(self.typeFrame)
        for column, wordType in enumerate(['Noun', 'Verb', 'Adjective', 'Adverb'], 1):
            typeRadioButton = tk.Radiobutton(self.typeFrame, text = wordType, textvariable = self.typeVar, value = wordType, command = self.createLambda(wordType))
            typeRadioButton.grid(row = 1, column = column)
        self.typeFrame.grid()

    def createLambda(self, obj):
        return lambda: self.changeInfo(obj)

    def changeInfo(self, obj):
        pass # this will do something later
```

However, when I run the code like this, the Radiobuttons have no text associated with them.

```
root = tk.Tk()
test_instance = Test(root)
test_instance.master.mainloop()
```

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `textvariable=...` to `variable=...`.

BTW, your example does not contain `self.typeFrame.pack()` or `self.typeFrame.grid(..)`.

Comment: Heh, it's a part of a larger class so I forgot to include that. Thanks  for the help!